# Mp3 files and Vue-loader

Tags: audio, vue.js, vue-loader

I'm tying to load a mp3 file in my Vue component: (I'm using the Vue-CLI boilerplate)

```
const sound = new Audio(require("./sound.mp3")))
```

But I'm getting this error:

`Unexpected character ‘’ (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Here is a minimal project demonstrating the error: https://github.com/life4ants/vue-audio-test

Comment: Do you definitely have `file-loader` installed?

Comment: @thanksd Yes, it's in my package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding the following to `build/webpack.base.conf.js` fixed the problem:

```
  {
    test: /\.mp3$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

the app at the above link has been updated and now works.